# sql запрос с параметром

Tags: sql

Запрос применяется для выгрузки значений поля в файл DBF
Запрос идет с параметром, кто нибудь - может перевести на русский, что там  происходит (загвоздка в том, что с выборкой параметров, я не работал)

```
select (
  select par.partner_name
  from t_partner par
  where inc.ext_partner_id = par.partner_id
) as part,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не запрос с параметром, а коррелированный подзапрос. Означает он следующее:

```
select (                 -- выбрать
select par.partner_name  -- выбрать partner_name 
from t_partner par       -- из таблицы t_partner, которую мы тут назовём именем par
where inc.ext_partner_id -- где ext_partner_id из текущей записи таблицы inc 
= par.partner_id         -- равно partner_id таблицы par
) as part,               -- и назвать это именем part
```

Но лучше этот ужастик переписать на JOIN и избавиться от подзапроса.

Comment: но таблицы inc - у меня нет в базе ?

Comment: @OlegFalaleevNASLINI inc - это алиас. Он наверняка объявлен ниже (в той части запроса, что вы не показали)

Comment: А алиас такой в источнике данных запроса - есть.

Comment: как сюда весь код кинуть ?

Comment: @OlegFalaleevNASLINI Ссылка **править** под текстом вопроса. Нажать. Изменить текст. Сохранить.